# Accidentally turned off display/screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

I have a HP elitebook 840 running Windows 7. My problem started when I was holding the laptop and dripped some juice from the plate of food I was also holding. I started to clean off the little bit of juice (mainly on the corner, a little bit on the keys) and as I was doing so I pressed a bunch of the corner keys where the FN, CTRL, TAB and Power button is. I accidentally pressed the power button and the screen turned off, and laptop hibernated (normal, set to hibernate when power button pressed). Then when I tried to turn it on again, everything looks normal (keyboard backlight comes on, fan turns on) but the display doesn't show anything, not even any backlight.
The only other thing I've noticed is that the CAPSLOCK and NUMLOCK keys flash 5 times when booting up, which might be normal, I've just never noticed before.

I have tried doing a hard reset by powering off the laptop, removing the battery, press and holding the power button for 60 secs, plugging in power cable and turning back on. Can't get the display to work at all :( I've tried plugging a VGA cable, attached to a monitor, but there is no signal to the monitor. Please what could I do to fix this?

Comment: Ok, so I forgot to ask. Is there a combination of keys that turn off the display driver, that I may have accidentally pressed? I would have just thought that I broke the LCD, but the external monitor shows nothing either...

Comment: Does anything appear when you turn on the laptop, or it disappears only after Windows boots? If nothing appears at all even after restarting/turning your laptop on, that means your motherboard got damaged because of the juice.

Comment: Nothing appears, just the keyboard backlights and fan turn on. However, if I press a bunch of keys it starts beeping a bit after a while. Also, sometimes when I left it running for a while, the disability helper comes on and starts reading out screen options. So I know that the laptop is still running despite the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I've noticed is that the CAPSLOCK and NUMLOCK keys flash 5 times

This indicates a **General system board failure**.

Maybe some of the liquid has gone inside and damaged your motherboard.

Please try the troubleshooting suggestions below.

---

#### Troubleshooting LED Blink Codes or Beep Codes During Startup or Boot

> **Startup Symptom:  LEDs blink or computer beeps but does not start**
>
> Use this document if the notebook does not start, but the LEDs near
>   the keyboard blink several times, or there are a series of beeping
>   sounds, just after the power button is pressed.
>
> The blinking LED lights on newer computers, or the beep tones on older
>   computers, will help support agent determine what hardware component
>   is not responding properly. The exact meaning of each code varies with
>   the model, and the user cannot change any of the blink or beep codes.
>
> **DO THIS FIRST - Perform a hard reset**
>
> If a PC suddenly fails to boot properly, you should perform a hard
>   reset as the first procedure.
>
> 1. Disconnect all peripheral devices and remove all USB devices and media cards. You want to test the computer not the accessories!
> 2. Disconnect the AC power adapter, remove the battery, and then press and hold the power button for at least 15 seconds .
> 3. Reconnect the AC power adapter (but do not connect the battery), Press the Power button, Look for glowing LEDs near caps lock and num
>      lock keys, and Listen for sounds of a disk drive and fan turning.
>
> [image]

...

> When there is a start-up problem and you see LED lights on the keyboard blink a few times (between 1 and 8 blinks), or hear a series of beep tones (between 1 and 6 tones), do the following actions. There is very little you can do to resolve blink or beep code messages until you contact an HP Support Agent or authorized HP Service center.
>
> **Recognize Blink Codes**
>
> With the development of the Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI)
>   environment, the HP Pavilion and Compaq Presario notebook computers
>   built in 2009 or later use blinking LEDS to identify hardware
>   component reporting an error during startup. The codes are not valid
>   for other models.
>
> 1. Press the power button to turn on the computer, and look for blinking LED lights on the keyboard.
> 2. Count the number of blinks in the sequence (between 1 and 8 blinks).
>
>    After the sequence of blinks or beeps, there is a pause for a few
>      seconds, and the sequence is repeated (usually 3 or 4 times). The
>      blink sequence can be repeated by pressing the power button again.

...

> **Get technical assistance**
>
> When you see blinking LEDs or hear beep tones, you should contact HP for technical assistance. Report the number of LED blinks, or the number and duration of the beep tones, and the model or product name of your computer. The Support Agent can help you troubleshoot the startup problem.

...

> [image]

Source [HP Notebook PCs - Troubleshooting LED Blink Codes or Beep Codes During Startup or Boot](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01732674)

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down all four arrow keys and then pressing the power button, this will recover the Bios and hopefully solve your issue.

For future reference, beeps and flashes all have meanings.
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01732674